# Are there any images of the USS Enterprise at night?

Tags: world-war-two, resource, ships

As the title says, are there any images of the (CV-6) USS Enterprise at night?
To specify I'm looking for the 1942 (or similar built version).

I'm especially interested in the runway lights, but in general  how the carrier looked at night.

Comment: There are more than one USS Enterprise. Based on your tags I suspect you're looking for CV-6 rather than CVN-65, but I suggest you edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Must it specifically be USS Enterprise, or would one of the other two Yorktown class carriers ([USS Yorktown (CV-5)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Yorktown_(CV-5)) and [USS Hornet (CV-8)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Hornet_(CV-8))suffice?

Comment: Convince me this isn't an **X-Y problem** - a problematic proposed solution to an unspecified problem. Please explain the base reason for this request, so that sensible alternatives can also be explored.

Comment: I would like to find out how the lights are placed on that carrier at that time and how it was lit, however I can not find a single usable image of that ship at night (at that time).

Comment: @TomasBy: That comment, expanded, might be the best answer possible.

Comment: A Yorktown class Carrier is sufficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to see is a general plan.

If you go here
    https://www.hnsa.org/manuals-documents/booklets-of-general-plans-online/

You will find a great long list of ships for which the website has general plans.  Scrolling down the list you will find CV-5 USS Yorktown, the class leader, and you can down load the plans from there

Or you can trust me and directly link from here
    https://www.hnsa.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/cv5.pdf

Page six shows the location of the landing lights embedded in the douglas fir flight deck planking.

The same set of plans may be had at
  https://maritime.org/doc/plans/

Answer (score 2):

[This is for the period 1944-45](http://cv6.org/ship/logs/nite_op_material.htm#lighting), not 1942.

> Deck Lighting
>
> The deck lighting used successfully on this ship is comprised of the
>   normal night lighting furnished carriers with the exception that the
>   flush-deck lights have not proven satisfactory. Borrowing an idea from
>   the INDEPENDENCE, a set of lights, hereinafter known as "Victory
>   Lights", have been installed. Since their use was started, the planes
>   have lined up with the deck many times better and not a single plane
>   has gone over the side.
>
> The victory light consists of a vertical member on deck 6" by 21" and
>   constructed of rubber (similar to "stop" signs which may be run over
>   by cars) with the after side painted white. A strip painted white and
>   of the same dimensions is painted on the inboard side on deck, the 21"
>   dimensions being fore and aft. A small (20-watt) light is mounted on
>   deck to shine on the vertical member at an angle of 45°. (Deck guide
>   lights are recommended for this light but to date they have not been
>   available and a homemade housing has been in use). The lights are
>   controlled by a rheostat. They are placed as far outboard on deck as
>   possible and still form a straight line from the number one barrier to
>   the ramp. Nine are in this line on the port side and four on the
>   starboard side abeam of the first four on the port side. Four lights
>   are all necessary on the starboard side as the pilot only uses them to
>   line himself up after the cut and he can't see further aft on deck
>   than the fourth light at that time.
>
> The standard red deck edge lights on both sides are arranged with
>   every other one turned out on the starboard quarter 30°. This allows
>   the pilot to pick these lights up early and has proven a big help in
>   aiding pilots to line themselves up with the deck sooner than was the
>   case before they were turned.
>
> The combination of the pilot being able to line himself up earlier and
>   the wider span of the victory lights has proven its worth in
>   operations. Pilots are also universal in their acclaim of the
>   improvement in depth perception with the loom of the victory lights as
>   contrasted to the direct light of the flush deck lights. The flush
>   deck lights are kept open to be used only as a standby in case of a
>   failure of the victory lights.

I doubt there are pictures, though.

(And [here is another link](https://thanlont.blogspot.com/2012/04/night-carrier-landings-in-beginning.html) with relevant info.)

Comment: For illustrative purposes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:USS_Antietam_(CVA-36)_underway_at_night_in_1953_(80-G-K-16893).jpg & perhaps this book has pics (not in preview) https://books.google.de/books?id=k5in_y78gw4C&dq=%22victory+lights%22+enterprise+war&hl=de

Comment: The USS Antietam picture is after her conversion to an angle deck carrier, Antietam was the first such conversion, 1952.  Barrett's Enterprise book does have pictures which show the lights, in the daytime, if you know what you're looking for . . . see third page of the photo section, bottom photo.  Take in the Battle of Midway period.  Small white lines running parallel with the length if the ship, these are painted on the deck; crossing the T at the forward end of each painted line are the deck lights.

Comment: Sorry, that's "running parallel with the length OF the ship